# How do I add wireframes to instanced meshes in Three.js

Tags: three.js, instance, mesh, wireframe

I am implementing a custom cityscape scene in Three.js. I need to render a lot of the same geometries and to increase speed I have implemented InstanceMesh.

For normal meshes, I have used this code to add wireframes to all meshes:

```
// material is created elsewhere
var geo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1, 1, item.height, 16, 16);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, this.createMaterial(object.material));
scene.add( mesh );
// creating wireframes    
var edgegeo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( geo ); 
var wire = new THREE.LineSegments( edgegeo, this.createMaterial("wire") );
scene.add( wire );
```

This also seemed to work:

```
mesh.add(wire)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work for instanced meshes since there does not seem to be an instanced version of LineSegments? How would I approach this problem?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the same thing as `EdgesGeometry`, you would have to manually create the line segments (instanced) and align them with the boxes. You'd have to align 12 instanced lines per box.

So if you have `10` boxes that are all under the same `InstancedMesh`, then you'd have a second `InstancedMesh` which has all lines, and you'd need `10 * 12` or `120` lines in the second `InstancedMesh`.

While you iterate on each box of the first `InstancedMesh`, you'd iterate over 12 lines of the second `InstancedMesh`.